# How do you prevent a single file to be pushed on git commit

Tags: git, github

I use the following line of code in the terminal to push my files to github:

```
Git init
Git add -A
Git commit -m "name"
Git push origin master
```

How do I prevent a file, lets say

```
hello.html
```

to be pushed/updated?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.gitignore` file in the repository that contains the relative path to the file. I.e.:

```
/path/to/hello.html
```

See [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) page for more information.

Comment: Is there a git line for that? How does it look like?

Comment: No. You create a file called `.gitignore` in the root of your repository. If your repository is called `repository` and `hello.html` resides in `repository/html/hello.html`, you would edit `repository/.gitignore` to contain the line `repository/html/hello.html`